# Ember.js: How to prevent refreshing nested routes?

Tags: ember.js

What's the Ember way to refresh middle route's model when query params changed? I could use something like this

```
queryParams: {
  qParam: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
}
```

in middle route, but it calls route's refresh function a refresh also its nested routes and it's inappropriate for me.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Generally you would want your middle route to refresh its model (which in turn would need to refresh its nested routes, as they are tied to the model you are refreshing). You might be able to alter your sub-routes to work differently, but would need more info...

Comment: Sure, I have some nested routes of which every has own query params/dynamic segment and is less or more logically independent of his parent route. So it is little bit nonsence and waste of network to reload their models if parent's query params change. And there is one more problem, the record in child route's model can be in updating phase, so if I reload it, I lose the update of it. In most cases I add only relationships to record in model when I update it, so I can not test if record is dirty.